# Clear-Site-Data "*" : Different behavior in both Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, cookies, browser, http-headers

I am facing an issue with:

```
Clear-Site-Data "*"
```

I have two domains using two web servers: `a.mywebsite.com` and  `b.mywebsite.com`

`'b'` is an iframe in `'a'`.

When I click logout, I call the logout first on `b.mywebsite.com/logout` and after `a.mywebsite.com/logout.`

`b.mywebsite.com` return in the html header `Clear-Site-Data "*"`

I noticed that in Firefox and Chrome, the behavior is diffrent.

***in the Chrome browser:***
After calling `b.mywebsite.com/logout` and return html header `Clear-Site-Data "*"`, it will clear all the cookies from all mywebsite.com, including `a.mywebsite.com` cookies, ***even though some cookies belong to only*** `'a'.`

***However, in Firefox,***
it only clears `b.mywebsite.com` or the common cookies between `a` and `b`.

This results in the Chrome user having their cookies cleared but not actually being logged out in the server side, as the server receives the request without any cookies.

*Question* :
Can someone help me in aligning the `Clear-Site-Data "*"` behavior in **Chrome** with **Firefox**? I aim to  `Clear-Site-Data "*"` clear only the cookies of site B or the common ones.

thanks.

Comment: It seems clear from [the standard](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/) that the Chrome behavior you describe is incorrect. I don't have any additional insight into this issue, but if you can't figure it out you could always file a [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the Chromium browsers related to how it handles the Clear-Site-Data header. Currently, when Clear-Site-Data is used in the Chromium browser, it cleans all cookies for any subdomain. In my case, this affects both website-a and website-b, contrary to the documentation, which suggests that it should only clean cookies for its subdomain.
I implemented a workaround to solve the issue. I executed a fetch request to the logout page from website-a to clear the session on the server side without including the Clear-Site-Data header to clear the browser cookies. After that I triggered the logout page from website-b by embedding it in an iframe, triggering the header to clear site data.
This approach effectively clears all cookies for website-a and website-b in Chromium browsers.
To clean website-a in Firefox, I made a second request to website-a to request the logout page, but this time asking to include Clear-Site-Data to clean the browser cookies.